# ¿Es posible iniciar debates de alguna forma?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, temática

Respecto a las preguntas realizadas en Stack Overflow, ¿es válido de alguna forma iniciar debates, basados en opiniones?

Como por ejemplo, *¿Qué DLL podría usar para tal cosa?* o *¿Qué es mejor, esto o esto y por qué?*

Y si no es válido, ¿hay algún sitio parecido para esto?

Si no existe, podría estar bien algún apartado para este tipo de cuestiones como tal.

Comment: Nótese que hay dos sitios para recomendaciones [softwarerecs.se] y [hardwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, en [StackOverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) las preguntas que no son susceptibles de recibir una respuesta específica se consideran de baja calidad y son cerradas. Cuando se vota para cerrar una pregunta de estas, el texto explica lo siguiente:

> Muchas buenas preguntas generan cierto grado de opinión según la experiencia de los expertos, pero casi todas las respuestas a esta pregunta estarán basadas en opiniones, en lugar de hechos, referencias o experiencia específica.

El problema con este tipo de preguntas es que cada uno tiene sus propias preferencias y experiencias con determinado producto, librería... que haría que se recibieran muchas respuestas diferentes en incluso se iniciaran debates inútiles sobre las ventajas de este sobre el otro. Este sitio **no es un foro**, se pretende tener preguntas y respuestas de calidad y que no sean específicas para una persona, sino que puedan ser útiles en el futuro para otros.

En cuanto a si existe algún sitio similar donde hacer ese tipo de preguntas, deberías buscar algún foro de programación (por ejemplo [La web del programador](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com) en sus tiempos era bastante conocida, aunque no se como anda últimamente), aunque yo te recomiendo que para consultas de ese tipo te pases por el [Chat de StackOverflow en español](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol),donde suele haber bastante gente y seguro que tratan de ayudarte con tu problema.

Puedes crear un chat propio para el tema que quieres discutir o mirar la [lista de salas ya creadas](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com) para ver si alguna trata el tema que buscas.
Muchas son creadas cuando los comentarios en las publicaciones se alargan más de lo debido.

Ten en cuenta que en el chat se puede leer con cualquier reputación, pero para participar necesitas 20 de reputación.

Answer (score 3):

En general no. Las preguntas deben ser concretas y debe ser posible darles una respuesta concreta y objetiva.

Pero en el caso particular de la etiqueta [revisión-de-código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revisi%c3%b3n-de-c%c3%b3digo) sí es posible algo similar. Podrías preguntar:

> Tengo una base de datos tal que así.
>
> [Esquema y código de la BD].
>
> Esta consulta tarda mucho y quiero mejorarla. He probado con tal y
>   tal. ¿Qué puedo mejorar en el diseño de la BD para optimizar la
>   consulta?